# jPlayer not playing right away

Tags: jquery, buffer, jplayer

I have jPlayer installed on a website and it works great in Chrome but in other browsers it waits to download the whole video before starting to play - If i look at the demos on the jPlayer website they all work fine in all browsers. Could there be something that i am doing which is stopping it working correctly?

Here is the code i am using: http://pastebin.com/KCWLi22C - not including the rest of the page..

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe it's an issue with the M4V file format (your code mentions M4V so I assume that's the format you're using).

The best format for streaming video in a Flash player is FLV. Or ideally switch to [HTML5 video](http://html5video.org/).

If you're stuck with M4V files [this thread](http://www.longtailvideo.com/support/forums/jw-player/setup-issues-and-embedding/3163/mp4-streaming-problem) has some suggestions on adjusting the files to allow streaming. The problem is that M4V files by default store important information at the start and at the end of the file, so it can't be played without the whole file being downloaded. By adjusting the file and moving all the important information to the start of the file it can begin playing immediately.

Hope that helps

Comment: Is there a reason it works okay for me using Chrome? I am not stuck with M4V, is there a format that both flash and HTML accept?

Comment: Chrome may be using a later Flash version - not sure there. You will  need to transcode the video into several formats for Flash and HTML5 video support. The [Kaltura video library](http://www.kaltura.org/project/HTML5_Video_Media_JavaScript_Library) can help